# PHP function - php + html together in one function

Tags: php

Its my first time trying this soo i am not sure it its going to correct way or how i could do something like this!! But what i want is an function with PHP and HTML together something like this.

```
function hoofdMenu1()
    {
        return '
        <!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
    <div class="container">
    <div id="hoofdmenu" class="col-xs-12  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

        foreach($aMenu as $entry)  
        {
            foreach($entry as $key)
            {
                $sClass='';
                if($entry["page"] == $_GET['page'] ) :
                $sClass= 'active';
                endif; 
                echo '
                <li class="'.$sClass.'" role="presentation"><a
                href="index.php
                page='.$entry["page"].'">'.$entry["title"].'</a></li>'; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I know this is bad, but i am looking for something like this that when you call the function it do work like it would normaly do.

Comment: Since it's your first time: I would strongly advise you not to use PHP and HTML in a mixture like this. I's good to know that before you embed this in multiple products.

Answer (score 1):

```
function hoofdMenu1()
    {
       $html = ' <div class="container">';
        $html .= ' <div id="hoofdmenu" class="col-xs-12  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">';
        $html .= ' <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">';

        foreach($aMenu as $entry)  
        {
            foreach($entry as $key)
            {
                $sClass='';
                if($entry["page"] == $_GET['page'] ) :
                $sClass= 'active';
                endif; 
                $html .= '<li class="'.$sClass.'" role="presentation"><a href="index.php" page='.$entry["page"].'">'.$entry["title"].'</a></li>'; 
                break;
            }
        }
            $html .= '</ul></div></div>';
        return $html ; 

    }
```

Comment: I get an 0 in return and not the content.

Comment: I got the Html code correct but when the PHP starts at foreach() nothing happends i dont get the content inside $aMenu

Comment: <?php echo var_dump($aMenu);?> check if $aMenu variable contain data or not.

Comment: I just did and i get the array just normal, only when i use it in the function it wont work.

Comment: make <?php global $aMenu ; ?>

Comment: Yes, making the array global at the top of the function did work thank you very much, now the only thing i need is to apply it to all my functions.

Comment: Update the code so i can accept it as answer!! insert the global $aMenu; in it and i will accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<?php
function hoofdMenu1()
{
    $return_string = '<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
                        <div class="container">
                            <div id="hoofdmenu" class="col-xs-12  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">';

    foreach($aMenu as $entry) 
    {
        foreach($entry as $key) 
        {
            $sClass='';
            if($entry["page"] == $_GET['page'] ) : $sClass= 'active'; endif; 

            $return_string .= '<li class="'.$sClass.'" role="presentation">
                                    <a href="index.php page='.$entry["page"].'">'.$entry["title"].'</a>
                               </li>';
            break;
        }
    }

    $return_string .= '</ul></div></div>';

    return $return_string;
}
?>
```

Comment: I got the Html code correct but when the PHP starts at foreach() nothing happends i dont get the content inside $aMenu.